# Is there a Python API function to get value by its name in C++?

Tags: python, c++

I want to do something like this:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("d = 0.97");
float a = ? // how to get value of d by its name?
Py_Finalize();
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that `d` ends up in the `__main__` module and you can use `PyModule_GetDict` to get its namespace `dict`.

Comment: `PyModule_GetDict` expect `*PyObject` as an argument, I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said tdelaney, "`d` ends up in the `__main__` module". So the best solution I find is

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("d = 0.97");
PyObject *mainModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject *var = PyObject_GetAttrString(mainModule, "d");
float a = PyFloat_AsDouble(var);
Py_Finalize();
```

Not as simple as I expected, but acceptable and it works.

Answer (score 1):

`PyRun_SimpleString` will not help AFAIK.

Use `PyRun_String` instead of `PyRun_SimpleString` which returns an object a pointer to a `PyObject`. But this would not be very (simple) as mentioned by your question

Comment: I used `PyRun_SimpleString` only to initialize variable. I expect something like `PyGet_Float("var_name")` (i made it up), but i don't know if something like this exist.