# getting a error message with Python/C API

Tags: c++, python-c-api

I was looking for a way to get error message from executing python code in C++. I tried some answers from [How to get Python exception text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418015/how-to-get-python-exception-text), but any of them worked for me. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    if (PyRun_SimpleString("something stupid")) {
        PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
        PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
        const char *errMsg = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject_Str(ptraceback));
        std::cout << errMsg;
    }
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

I expect to print something like that:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
something stupid
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But when I run code, `cout` prints:

```
<NULL>
```

Comment: There's a lot of error checking that you're missing tht you might help.  Check if `ptraceback` is NULL. Check if the result of  `PyObject_Str(ptraceback)` is NULL.

Comment: I checked and both are NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleStringFlags), when using `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags()` (or just `PyRun_SimpleString()`):

> If there was an error, there is no way to get the exception information.

So code must be runned the other way. Eventually, you can run in interpreter:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import traceback, sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("trace = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(sys.last_type, sys.last_value, sys.last_traceback))");
```

Then read `trace` from interpreter, similar like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63320285/13966135 .